# Using lxml in an IDE with code completion/auto complete

Tags: python, pydev, lxml, pycharm

I'm trying to use lxml in pycharm or eclipse using pydev, everything is working correctly except for code completion, it seems to be non-existant. Is there something I need to implement to get it to work with the classes from lxml?

For example:

```
import lxml.html
html = open('html.html', 'r').read()

root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
tds = root.cssselect("td.author")

print temp[0].text # I know that the text attribute exists but code completion doesn't show it
```

Note: Intelisense and smart help work for other things just not lxml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is usually a problem with modules written in C like `lxml`, where most parsers can only get the signature of a method but not the details. The signature of a python method doesn't have the return type so it's hard to guess the type of `tds`. This lack of information leads to the failure of the auto-complete feature.

Other than waiting for the IDEs' authors for improve their parsers, there's not much that you can do.

Comment: When you say authors, do you mean the authors of lxml or of the IDE?, also when I debug I can see all the attributes of tds

Comment: I meant the authors of the IDE. You can see the attributes when debug because the type of `tds` is determined at runtime and therefore can be inspect by a debugger. Code completion use a static parser that have to guess the type of tds without running the code.